# How to pass a parameter in stored procedure while dynamically adding columns in a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am getting a syntax error near @coll in alter statement. I have added a column in the same way, but not by any parameter. How can I do the same with a parameter?

```
create procedure sp1
@coll nvarchar(50) 
as
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'coll' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Students'))

begin 
    Alter table Students ADD @coll NULL
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this with dynamic SQL:

```
create procedure sp1 (
    @coll nvarchar(50) 
) as
begin
    if not exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = @coll and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Students'))

    begin 
        declare @sql nvarchar(max);
        set @sql = 'Alter table Students ADD [' + @coll + '] NULL';
        exec(@sql);
    end;
end;
```

Note:  I changed the `if` to use the variable.  Otherwise you are always checking for the name `'coll'`.

Or, better yet:

```
        set @sql = 'Alter table Students ADD ' + quotename(@coll) + ' NULL';
```

Comment: As soon as you answered, I found the solution. Nevertheless, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do that in very simple way as we have to check column existence in dynamic way too, and have to define column's [datatype] in alter portion otherwise if you want datatype also dynamic then just add another parameter and place that variable in datatype position in alter statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (@coll NVARCHAR(50)) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = '
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = ''' + @coll + ''' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(''Students''))      
    ALTER TABLE Students ADD ' + @coll + ' VARCHAR(20) NULL
ELSE 
    PRINT (''Column Already Exist'')'

EXEC(@sql)
END
```